# Opencv how to fix xfeatures2d error in .lib file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++, .lib

I am trying to use opencv's feature matcher so I download opencv's extra modules and moved the xfeatures2d.hpp file into include/opencv2 but when ever I try to run Local Windows Debuger I get two errors this:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: static struct cv::Ptr __cdecl cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create(double,int,int,bool,bool)" (?create@SURF@xfeatures2d@cv@@SA?AU?$Ptr@VSURF@xfeatures2d@cv@@@3@NHH_N0@Z) referenced in function main TheRealFlannBasedMatcher    C:\Users\Jacks\source\repos\TheRealFlannBasedMatcher\TheRealFlannBasedMatcher\TheRealFlannBasedMatcher.obj  1

and this error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  TheRealFlannBasedMatcher    C:\Users\Jacks\source\repos\TheRealFlannBasedMatcher\x64\Debug\TheRealFlannBasedMatcher.exe 1

so I went through my included header files one at a time and the problem goes away way I comment out #include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp" but a whole new slew of problems pop up with the stuff that was relieing on it. so I did some digging online and I think that the problem lies with my linked opencv_world400d.lib file please help.

Comment: Did you link any library related with that header? I belive there is a library called "opencv_contrib" and you must build it yourself and then link to your project. You cannot use libraries by just including them in your project.

Comment: I downloaded the entire opencv_contrib master branch from GitHub but there was no .lib file

Comment: It shouldn't be already, it's normal if you couldn't see any compiled libs/dlls there. Because everybody working on different target platforms like win32, x64, linux etc and C++ produces machine code! So It's really rare to see precompiled libraries nowadays, everybody needs to compile the library for their environment. :) Btw, I didn't use that 'opencv_contrib' library, but I know that, firstly you have to compile it to produce libs/dlls then you can link them together with your project.