# creating a .lib file for the opencv module xfeatures2d

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, .lib

I am trying to use [opencv's FlannBasedMatcher](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d6f/tutorial_feature_flann_matcher.html) in visual studio but to do that I need to use an opencv module called xfeatures2d [I have actually already posted about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317036/opencv-how-to-fix-xfeatures2d-error-in-lib-file) but I have had a lot of trouble with making and including the .lib file if someone could tell me how to do it or link a really good tutorial that would be great.

Comment: Use vcpkg , an open source packager software, to install the opencv using a one liner command.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not or have a wrong xfeatures2d lib file in opencv/build/lib.
Maybe you didn't notice during the build of opencv using Cmake but you might not have built this library (or partially).

I recommend you to rebuild (delete the old build repository and create a new empty one) openCV using Cmake (graphic interface) and make sure you have the parameter "BUILD_opencv_xfeatures2d" enabled.
Then, check that you have no error during the generation because there sometimes are some issues with this lib. (If you have, you might need to generate with another internet connection or edit your proxy for this operation).

Look at this tutorial if you need to rebuild openCV : https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-opencv-and-extra-modules-from-source-using-cmake-and-then-set-it-up-in-your-pycharm-7e6ae25dbac5 
Hope it helps.

Comment: the only thing is that this is for Pycharm and I am using visual studio